# Configure Rspec to run on production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am working on this project where I do selects from the remote production database. My user only granted `SELECT` so it is relatively safe. However now I came to the point where I have to test query objects and this is a bit of pain.

But I can't run tests because it tries to drop database which is not allowed for my user. How do I configure Rspec so it doesn't do anything with db?

Right now I tested it like this in Rails Console by hand:

```
expected = {...}

QueryObject.new.call
# SELECT ...

_ == expected
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, testing against live databases is a Bad Idea.

Extract some sample data from the production database and add it to your test database, using fixtures or factories. Then you can perform queries against the test database without fear of:

1. Data in the production database changing and throwing off the tests, producing "false negatives";
2. Your test being run in the wrong environment by another user (with greater privileges) and modifying the production database unintentionally.
3. Dragging down performance by running tests while the application is in use.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should've added this as disclaimer to my question.